# How to change row button class base on column value

Tags: c#, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I define an action button in each table row and I wish to change the button  class to awesome font icon base on another column value.

Kindly refer to the sample code below, I want to change the `actionbtn`'s  icon base on `btnval` after table is loaded. For example, when `btnval=""`, `actionbtn`  class will be `fas fa-check` else `fas fa-undo`.

Can anyone advise how can I do it right?
Thank you.

```
<table class="table ew-table" >
    <thead>
        <tr class="ew-table-header">
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>BtnValue</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @for (int i = Table1_List.StartRowCount; i <= Table1_List.RowCount; i++)
        {
         <tr>
          <td style="width: 30px !important; max-width:30px;">
            <button id="actionbtn" type="button">
                 <i class="fas fa-check"></i>    
            </button>
          </td>
          <td> 
             <a>Table1_List[i].resultval</a>
          </td>
          <td>
             <a>Table1_List[i].btnval</a>
          </td>
         </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: why change after load? what template language is @for coming from? use that language to set the icon on load.

Comment: Hi, it is mvc core view page. I have tried using <i class="@Table1_List[i].btnval" /> but it return text in the column instead of icon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for the link. Topic and answer in this are on element onclick assignment and I have no issue on that. Anyway, I managed to get it work thru a hard way. I created a function to loop thru the table and assign the class according to btnval's cell value.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work within the for-loop:

`<i class="fas @(Table1_List[i].btnval=''?' fa-check':' fa-undo')"></i>`